# Google Maps Android App

Tags: android, api, google-maps

I am making an android app that involves displaying locations on a map. Should I make an API that serves the locations? How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a source of data. Building an api is a good choice. To display markers in a given location you need at least the longitude and latitude.

You can have simple objects with lat/long
 and a description to show in a tooltip/infoWindow

Comment: What sources might I need to find to help to try and figure out a an approach close to the "best"?

Comment: If you are building an app that will go into production. An app that will be actually used by people other than yourself, the API solution in my humble opinion is the best way to achieve this. On the other hand if you are just practicing/learning you can have an hardcoded object in your code and use that for locations. For example, I built an app that that makes use of Maps SDK. 
To display the locations of the client facilities, I query my API built in Spring Boot. But seriously that thing you said before about Mongo and flask seems perfect.

Comment: Yeah, it'll be used by others. In that case, I'll go with that solution I mentioned. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Map SDK:
[Google Map SDK Documents](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/intro)

Comment: Yes, but I was more curious about the data source. Hence why I asked about API.

Comment: Do you have any spisific problem using this SDK?

Comment: No, I'll use it, but it's not a data source is it. It's more like a front end? Like for displaying the actual map or dealing it's various attributes and properties. Right? I was just curious how to go about setting up the data source -backend.

Comment: Yes, it's correct.
It really depends on your idea. If you want to develop apps like Uber, it really needs a backend with a panel to control everything. But if you just wanna save user's location on your server, you just need a simple API which connects to the database and saves the location on that. Then you can use this location wherever you want

Comment: I see. Thanks a ton!